# Что означает null! (null с восклицательным знаком)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Встретил в C# коде такое выражение в контексте работы с БД через EF:

```
public DbSet<MyType> MyData { get; set; } = null!;
```

Что означает равенство свойства null с восклицательным знаком?

Comment: как ее понимать? Просто даже хз как загуглить, не ищется толком.

Comment: гуглить по английски: [null with exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755850/postfix-exclamation-operator-in-c-sharp) в доках она называется [Null Forgiving Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) [Nullable Reference типы в C# 8.0](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/455230/)

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это фича из c# 8.0, где ввели Nullable Reference types

Т.е. раньше вы писали String или string и было понятно, что string - это ссылочный тип, а потому может быть null (в отличие допустим от int, которому не присвоить null)

А начиная с c# 8 вы можете указать компилятору при помощи NullableContextOptions  = enable что string в коде и другие ссылочные типы не могут принимать null.

И вот как раз восклицательный знак после null -- это т.н. [null-forgiving оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving), который позволяет указать что значение null допустимо.

Больше информации по теме:

- [MSDN Ru: Null Forgiving Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)
- [MSDN Ru: Ссылочные типы, допускающие значение null](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)
- [Habr: Nullable Reference типы в C# 8.0](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/455230/)
- [en so: null with exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57755850/postfix-exclamation-operator-in-c-sharp)
- [Habr: Nullable Reference не защищают, и вот доказательства](https://habr.com/ru/company/pvs-studio/blog/522228/)